# ASP.Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages event handler not working in production

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using ASP.NET 3.1 Core Razor Pages and trying to add real time interaction for my dropdown list upon the onchange event.

I have two dropdown list, first one is filled with governorates and the second will be filled with cities of the selected governorate using onchange event.

[image]

All things go well with me while working in development, but if I publish my project the real time interaction does not happen for the city drop down list and I get this error

> GET http://localhost/SectorPlan/Update?handler=GetCitiesList&GovernorateId=15 404 (Not Found)

This is my code.

**Update.cshtml.cs**

```
public JsonResult OnGetGetCitiesList(int GovernorateId)
    {
        var cities = manageCities.GetCities().Where(c => c.GovId == GovernorateId).ToList();

        return new JsonResult(cities);
    }
```

**Update.cshtml**

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Governarate.Id">Governorate Name</label>
            <select class="form-control governarateDropdown" asp-for="Governarate.Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Governarates,"Id", "Name"))">
                <option selected disabled>Select Governorate</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Governarate.Id" class="alert-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
             <label asp-for="City.Id">City Name</label>
             <select class="form-control cityDropdown" asp-for="City.Id">
                 <option selected disabled>Select City</option>
              </select>
              <span asp-validation-for="City.Id" class="alert-danger"></span>
         </div>
```

**JS Code**

```
//Bind City dropdownlist
$(".governarateDropdown").change(function () {
    var govId = $(this).val();
    console.log(govId);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/SectorPlan/Update?handler=GetCitiesList',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $.param({ GovernorateId: govId }),
        success: function (result) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            var item = "";
            $(".cityDropdown").find('option').not(':first').remove();
            item += '<option selected disabled value="">Select City</option>'
            $.each(result, function (i, city) {
                console.log(city);
                item += '<option value="' + city.id + '">' + city.name + '</option>'
            });
            $(".cityDropdown").html(item);
        }, //End of AJAX Success function  

        failure: function (result) {
            //alert(result.responseText);
            console.log(result.responseText);
        }, //End of AJAX failure function  
        error: function (result) {
            //alert(result.responseText);
            console.log(result.responseText);
        } //End of AJAX error function  

    });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The error says the endpoint "`http://localhost/SectorPlan/Update`" is not found. Is the port wrong? Is "SectorPlan" wrong? does it need to be https? Everything is hardcoded, thus has to be maintained manually. Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try using the Url.PageLink method like so.

```
type: "GET",
url: "@Url.PageLink(pageHandler:"GetCitiesList", pageName:"/SectorPlan/Update",values: route values if you have any)",
```

Comment: I have used your suggestion for the url and it works, thanks.